# I don't understand this example of a closure

Tags: javascript

Crockford had this example to keep myArray from being in the global scope:

```
var myName = (function() {
    var myArray = ['zero','one','two','three','four'];
    return function(X) {
        return myArray[X];
    }
}()); // This function is invoked immediately

result = myName(3); // Now invoke it "for real"
```

Q: I don't get why it isn't

```
var myName = (function(X) {
```

Q: When I call myName(3), isn't "var myArray=" executed a 2nd time?
Suppose it's not executed a 2nd time because JavaScript knows that it's already been defined...  What about a loop or some other logic between the var stmt and the return function stmt?  Wouldn't it be executed every time?

Q: Can you name the subfunction and call it instead of calling myName?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

okay, let's break this down...

```
var myName = (function(){
    ...
}());
```

that piece sets `myName` to whatever that anonymous function *returns*, so if it were:

```
var myName = (function(){ return 42; }());
```

`myName` would equal `42`.  If that doesn't make sense, this is the same thing:

```
function someFunction(){ return 42; }
var myName = someFunction();
```

So in your example, `myName` is set to `function(X){ return myArray[X] }`.  So myName ***is*** a function.  When you call it, the only code that is run is `return myArray[x]`.  `myArray` is kept in what is called a *closure*, it is only exposed to the `myName` function and the anonymous one surrounding it.

I wrote an article on closures years back that may help you: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/article.php/3606701/Javascript-Basics-Part-9.htm (scroll down to the "Closures" header).

Comment: I was writing an answer in the same vein as this, good answer.

Comment: `myName` **is** set to ... (*you have is not*)

Comment: I think what you mean is `var myName = someFunction;`, no?

Comment: I don't know why I typed `not`... My hands don't always type what my head wants them to :)

Comment: @harpo - no, I was showing that as a simpler example of what the anonymous function execution actually does  :)

Comment: So "var myName = (function() {" is returning a function definition, and that function definition has a closure namespace...

Comment: Oooh.  "Javascript Basics Part 9".  That means there's a part 1-8!

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn & parts 10-13 :)

Comment: In that case I think the example only confuses matters, but I guess the OP disagrees.

Answer (score 3):

OK here it goes ..
answer to Q1  . it is not myName = (function(x) because the part inside the brackets returns a function which takes X . i.e. myname is not assigned to (function(){}) but to the return value of it .

Q2. No when u calll myName 2nd time it already points to the inner function hence the outer function is not invoked at all .(this is the sepciality of closures where the value stays alive in inner function even if outer functions are completed.)

Q3. Well nopes we can name the inner function but the name will be valid only inside the outer function and since outer function has completed the name would be useless.

Comment: "myname is not assigned to (function(){}) but to the return value of it".  Oh.  It's starting to make sense now...

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

The outer function doesn't have to have an argument `X`, because it's only purpose is to return another function (which then is parametrized). Thus no argument is needed here.

Thus the only effect is to bind the `function(X)...` thing to the variable `myName`. Therefore no other constructs like loops or so does make sense here.

Comment: "bind the function(X)...to the variable myName".  OK.  Yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Q1+2: Note the `()` right of the comment "This function is invoked immediately". The outer function defined is not stored in `myName`, but immediatly called. Itself then returns an anonymous function which has no name and requires a single parameter (`X`). This function beeing returned is stored in myName.

To grasp closure you should start thinking about functions just as another value of a variable which can be stored and returned jsut as any other value.

Q3: myName *is* the subfunction.

Comment: "start thinking about functions just as another value".  Oh.

Comment: "myName is the subfunction".  Ohhhh.

Answer (score 1):

Okay answer in turn:

First, why it's `var myName = (function() {` and not `var myName = (function(x) {`

In this case because the `x` value isn't required to create the function you are returning. The data structure of the array contained in the returned function is hard coded and so you don't need additional information to construct it. Much in the same way that

```
function a() { 
  return 1 + 2;
}
```

Doesn't have any arguments, because it's values are hardcoded. This is an example of functions as data or [first class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)

Question two: is `var myArray` executed every time.

The short of it is no. myArray has been assigned to at this point so it has a value that the system has already calculated. In this case it's a function. The myArray potion has been set and so there is no cause to keep executing it. If the outer function didn't return a new function then yes it would need to get called again and again but that would defeat the purpose of this abstraction.

Question three: can you call the inner function.

No, it's out of scope. The entire point of this example is that you have defined a function generator.

Comment: Actually you can name the inner function as long as you expose it.  For instance `return (window.foo = function(){ ... })` would work fine since it's what `myName` is being set to.

Comment: Well yes, but that changes the scope on the function. the way it's written you could not just say return a = function( .... and then call a later

Comment: No it doesn't, the function would still have the scope bound to the anonymous function wrapping it.  It's pointless in this example since `myName` would be identical to `window.foo`, but I'm pointing out that `window.foo` would work fine.  I think you're confusing scope with the parent object (in this case `window`, e.g. "Namespace") of the function.  Scope is only relevant to what the function has ___access___ to, not where the function resides.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to first question:
no, the first "line" is returning a function so when you call "myName" you are actually executing the returned function

```
function(X) {
        return myArray[X];
}
```

Answer to second question

no, such a function can still refer to the array "myArray"... in fact the purpose of this closure is to make myArray available in the global scope

Comment: "so when you call "myName" you are actually executing the returned function".  So it computes everything, and then stores what's to the right of the return statement into memory so that the first time it's referenced, it is a function definition.  OK.  I think I'm getting it.

Comment: since the returned function still refers to myArray, myArray stays in memory and doesn't get removed when exiting the main function executed on the first line

Answer (score 1):

In words:

`myName` is the result of an immediately executed anonymous function. It returns a function reference (to an anonymous function). That function has one parameter: `X`. After execution of the topmost anonymous function, `myName` is a reference to the inner anonymous function.

Now the inner anonymous function has access to `myArray` via a closure (`myArray` and the returned anonymous function both live within the scope of the topmost anonymous function). So if you execute `myName`, you actually execute the inner anonymous function, which can access `myArray`.

The topmost anonymous function is executed immediately and once (it returns a reference to the inner function). So `myArray` is declared within that execution context, and only once.

Comment: "myName is the result of an immediately executed anonymous function."  So myName IS the anonymous function.  Ohhh.  It doesn't RUN the anonymous function every time it's called, it _IS_ the anonymous function.  Oooh.  JavaScript is tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Since the definition of the myName object (function) ends in '()', its function is called immediately, returning a new function which has the myArray variable statically bound to it. myName is then accessible globally but myArray is not as it is within a function closure. When you reference myName() it has exclusive access to the bound array.

Comment: "myArray variable statically bound to it".  Like the STATIC variable declaration in VB.  I get it.

Comment: Yep, that's basically what it's about. It can be done like this because in javascript functions are first class: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function

Answer (score 0):

This approach ensures that myArray is only allocated once, when the outer function 'is invoked immediately'. After it is invoked, myArray isn't in the global scope, but is still available to the anonymous inner function.

The approach you proposed would work, but would require that the array be allocated each time the function was called. (Or be allocated outside the function, in the global scope.)

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn I didn't find your comment helpful. Care to elaborate?

Comment: You said that this approach "would require that the array be allocated each time the function was called", but that's not true.

Comment: I was referring to this part of the question: "don't get why it isn't var myName = (function(X) {" - this would require the array to either be globally allocated or allocated each time in the function.